# pandas: how to extend along minor-axis by merging with another Panel

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge, panel

I have two panels both with the same columns ('Open', 'Close', 'Volume' etc), the major_axis is a datetime and the minor_axis are stock symbols.

I want to join / merge the two together such that the columns do not change, but that I now have all stock symbols along the minor axis.

Note that it is not guaranteed the datetimes in the major_axis will be exactly the same, I need an outer join (or equivalent).

As suggested by the docs I am doing:

```
 p1.join(p2, how='outer')
```

but get the error:

```
ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index([u'Open', u'High', u'Low', u'Close', u'Volume', u'Adj Close'], dtype='object')
```

If I do specify a suffix I end up with 12 columns.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `pd.concat` with `axis=2`

***example***

```
tidx = pd.date_range('2015-03-31', periods=3, freq='M')

list1 = ['IBM', 'APPL']
list2 = ['CVX', 'BHP']

items = ['Open', 'Close', 'High', 'Low']

p1 = pd.Panel(np.random.rand(4, 3, 2), items, tidx, list1)
p2 = pd.Panel(np.random.rand(4, 3, 2), items, tidx, list2)

# <- This is the answer ->
pd.concat([p1, p2], axis=2).to_frame()
```

[image]

Comment: That works thanks. Presumably I can pass join='outer' to the concat method to handle datetimes not being exactly the same? (e.g london vs new york holidays)

Comment: @RichardH `'outer'` is the default... and yes.